# Why is an entropy of $\text{log}(n)$ only compatible with the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I have a random variable $X$ and want to show that having an entropy 
$$ H(X) = - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \text{log}(p_i) = \text{log}(n)$$ is equivalent to the distribution of $X$ being uniform.

Starting with the distribution is straightforward but I don't see how I can deduce the other implication.

Comment: This is the Shannon diversity index I think, this might help (or it may not): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index

Answer (score 5):

Use [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) with $f(t) = \log t$.
$$H(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac{1}{p_i}\leq \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \frac{1}{p_i}\right) = \log n$$
$\log t$ is strictly concave, so equality requires $p_i = 1/n$, for all $i$, (in other words, a **uniform distribution**).

Answer (score 3):

Consider $e^{H(x)} = \prod (\frac{1}{p_i})^{p_i}$

By [weighted AM-GM Inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality)

$\prod (\frac{1}{p_i})^{p_i} \leq \sum \frac{1}{p_i} \times p_i$ $\implies$ $\prod (\frac{1}{p_i})^{p_i} \leq n$

For the equality to hold: $\frac{1}{p_i} = \frac{1}{p_j}$ for any $i,j$ or equivalently $p_i = p_j$.

And hence $$p_i=\frac{1}{n}$$